# File opening observe in Mac

Tags: objective-c, observers

I would like to ask if there's any way to can observe the files that are opened in a Mac.

For the moment I am observing the files that are being created, modified or deleted with the FileSystemMonitor class.

Any help will be welcomed

**EDIT**:

This is what I have for the moment:
With this code I can monitor the updates, inserts and deleted of files in the desired folders. But I can't monitor the file opening.

```
#import "FileSystemMonitor.h"

#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

@implementation FileSystemMonitor

FSEventStreamRef stream;
NSFileManager *fileManager;
dispatch_queue_t dispatchEventQueue;

- (id)initWithPathsToWatch: (NSArray *) pathsToWatch
                eventQueue: (dispatch_queue_t) eventQueue{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        dispatchEventQueue = eventQueue;

        void *selfPointer = (__bridge void *)self;
        FSEventStreamContext context = {0, selfPointer, NULL, NULL, NULL};
        NSTimeInterval latency = 3.0;

        stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                     &fsevents_callback,
                                     &context,
                                     (__bridge CFArrayRef) pathsToWatch,
                                     kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow,
                                     (CFAbsoluteTime) latency,
                                     kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents
                                     );

        FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(stream,
                                         CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                                         kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
        FSEventStreamStart(stream);
    }

    return self;
}

void fsevents_callback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                       void *userData,
                       size_t numEvents,
                       void *eventPaths,
                       const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                       const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[])
{


    char **paths = (char**)eventPaths;
    //Here we do whatever we want to do with the events
}
```

Also don't know if will help or not, but when I want to get the date of a file's last modification I need to use the following code:

```
NSDictionary* fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:nil];
NSDate* lastUpdate = [fileAttributes objectForKey:@"NSFileModificationDate"];
```

And when want to get the last opening of a file:

```
MDItemRef item = MDItemCreate(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)fullPath); 
NSDate *lastOpened = (NSDate*)CFBridgingRelease(MDItemCopyAttribute(item, kMDItemLastUsedDate)); 
CFRelease(item);
```

So for reading the last opening date of a file I need to use MDItem class. Maybe this is the reason why I am not able to monitor the opened files

Comment: If you show a bit of what you have tried so far, you may be able to get more response...

Comment: Perhaps you can see how lsof does it: 
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lsof/